# why a page is loading too slow? How to solve it?

Tags: http

My friend had a interview and were asked what are the reasons could causing web page loading to slow? And what are the ways to solve it? What would be comprehensive answer to the question?

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow because it is too broad.

Answer (score 4):

Webpage slowness can be caused by all sorts of things

Could be as simple as a **bad connection**

**Inefficient Javascript code** For example, making more calls to the server than necessary. Or processing client side taking too long.

**Inefficient Backend code** Your front end requests take forever to process on the server.

**Server overloaded** so it could not handle the traffic.

Could also be **Unnecessarily large resources** For example downloading super large images just to shrink them down. Large javascript files that you are not using

There are even entire tools to analyze your site and see what may be slowing it down https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/

I could go on and on. Your question is extremely broad. Perhaps you have some specific questions?